# Loop after successful authentication between my SP and IDP with JBoss 7.4 SAML

Tags: java, jboss, saml, idp

I'm currently having an issue between my SP (Java 17 application deployed in an EAR) and the IDP. Once it successfully authenticates with the IDP, it returns to the SP but gets stuck in an infinite loop from which it doesn't exit, even though the SAML responses to the SP URL seem to be correct. I can't find a solution to the problem.

[standalone.xml configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4l5d.png)

[Console logs Jboss DEBUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNkMs.png)
I greatly appreciate possible solutions as I can't find the reason why this is happening.

I tried changing the configuration of my IDP and also my standalone.xml file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.